# Define an Oracle sequence with a pattern

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, sequence

First of all, i hope that this kind of question is accepted meaning by that a reflexion about a problem (that is pretty complex) and a possible solution (even simple ideas are welcomed).

So let's take a ride to the brainstorming world !

Let's suppose i have a table "product" and in it i have two fields called "prd_id" and "prd_num". 
- "prd_id" is the primary key and is incremented with an Oracle sequence (mySeq.nextval).
- "prd_num" is a copy of the "prd_id" and is primary used for display/logic purpose.

The problem is that the "prd_num" is becoming too complex (regarding its use) for the user.

So the idea is to create a new sequence that will increment the field "prd_num" along the incrementation of the "prd_id" (with the old sequence) BUT what's different here is that we would be able to specify a certain pattern (maybe using an xml config file, etc..) based on the client using the app (the distinction beetween clients is done via an another field in the table "product".

Exemple : for the client1 we would define the pattern "CLT1XXXX" with XXXX being a simple incrementation.

SO => I don't think that Oracle can handle this type of sequences (mixing letters with numbers in a certain pattern) so any ideas in Java/hibernate are welcomed.

Hope to hear some ideas !

Comment: An oracle sequence will only generate a number.  You could build a PL/SQL function that prepends whatever you would like to it.  But if prd_num is number, you won't be able to store it in the table.

Comment: I also can change its structure if i have to.

Comment: You will be best off using a pl/sql function to prepend a value to the sequence, returning the concatenated prefix and sequence value to the (for example) insert statement. For the record, you can also do it in a plain sql query as well.  "select 'CLT1'||to_char(myval_from_sequence) from sequence_name", for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers, for example a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. That way you can populate the column with a value, based on other column's values.

For example:

```
create or replace trigger product_insert
before insert on product
begin
  :new.prd_num := :new.column_with_client_distinction || to_char(:new.prd_id);
end;
/
```

(please note that Hibernate is not automatically aware of any column value that is populated by a trigger).

Comment: This is a nice solution, it could help me a lot ! But what would be the problem abount Hibernate being unable to be aware of the trigger populating the column ? I mean when i'll do my select (or update or other) Hibernate will go to the database and will get me the value that was set by the trigger ..

Comment: Yes it would. However, in some situations, Hibernate will not fetch the record again from the database (e.g. directly after the save) because it thinks it already knows all current column values and tries to minimize database roundtrips.

Comment: The cache ! Damn it lol, maybe there is a workaround about that .. i'll dig into hibernate cache's documentation. Anyway thanks for the idea ;)